# Overwrite ansible executable in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm wondering if it is possible to overwrite the `executable` value set in your `ansible.cfg` file within a playbook. Something like below...

```
---
- name: 'New Server Setup'
  hosts: 'all'
  gather_facts: false
  pre_tasks:
    - name: 'setup : installing python for ansible'
      raw: 'test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)'
      changed_when: false
    - setup: # aka gather_facts
      tags: setup
  user: root
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  executable: '/bin/bash'

  roles:
    - setup
```

I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per ansible,

Starting in version 2.1 this can be overridden by the inventory var ansible_shell_executable.